# sql server rounding depending on decimal value

Tags: sql, decimal, rounding

I have a decimal (18,2) column and when I do my select would like for it to round up/down depending on the decimal value.

Example:

```
value
  1.50  ->  2
  1.25  ->  1
```

so the basic decimal rule: >= .5 rounds up and < .5 round down
I've seen "Ceiling" round ups and "Floor" rounds down but I need to do both depending on the value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ROUND() Function something like this....

```
SELECT ROUND(Value,0)
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18574/1)

Comment: lol thanks! just found it too. I'll mark your answer in 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use round function to round the column value in select statement. Please try following

```
select ROUNDUP(COLUMN_NAME, 0) FROM TABLE_NAME
```